# Remove "V" letter in column names when a matrix without column names is converted to data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

When a matrix is converted to a date frame, the original column names are removed while **V1, V2, ...** are added as the new column names.

Is there any options to disable that? I expect the same column names as that in the matrix, e.g. 1, 2.

```
m <- cbind(1:2, 2:3); m

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3


as.data.frame(m)   

   V1 V2
1  1  2
2  2  3
```

Comment: Your matrix doesn't have column names. If you give it column names then they **are** preserved by `as.data.frame`: Try `m = cbind(1:2,2:3); colnames(m)=c("foo","bar")` then `as.data.frame(m)`.

Comment: m is a matrix, without names, try: `names(cbind(1:2, 2:3)); class(cbind(1:2, 2:3))`

Comment: Note that you can still refer to the column position as you would in a matrix, so `myMatrix[, 1]` and `myDf[, 1]` will pull the same vector in this example.

Comment: This question should be closed because it is a misreading of output. Unlikely to help the community

Comment: Thank every one for your input. I have really confused column indexes with column names.

Answer (score 4):

You said "When a matrix is converted to a date frame, the original column names are removed while V1, V2, ... are added as the new column names."

That's not the case. A matrix by default has no column names:

```
> m = matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
> colnames(m)
NULL
```

A data frame, however, has to have column names. If they aren't specified, it creates them in various ways. For example, if not specified in `data.frame`, they are named from the expression, with an X prefix:

```
> d = data.frame(1:2,3:4)
> colnames(d)
[1] "X1.2" "X3.4"
```

Or when converted from a matrix with no column names, it gets column numbers prefixed with a V, as you see:

```
> colnames(as.data.frame(m))
[1] "V1" "V2"
```

If the matrix *has* column names, then they are preserved by `as.data.frame`:

```
> colnames(m)=c("First","Second")
> as.data.frame(m)
  First Second
1     1      3
2     2      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing column names and column indexes, but if you really want to have numbers as column names they'll be turned into  character class.

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 3), 2)
colnames(m) <- c(1, 2)
rownames(m) <- c(1, 2)
m
#   1 2
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3

is.character(unlist(dimnames(m)))
# TRUE

ddf <- as.data.frame(m)
ddf
#   1 2
# 1 1 2
# 2 2 3
```